# Bing Maps V8 JS API Memory Leak Issues

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, bing-maps

**Overview:** This project I've been working on receives a message from an external source and updates a Bing Map based on the information received. However, when I let the page run for a long time, the page just ends up eating up all of the memory and crashing itself.

**Specifics:** This [memory issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL8X8.png) arose once I switched over to Bing Maps from Google Maps and I have not been able to resolve it no matter what I've tried. I've searched all over to try and either resolve this issue through Bing Maps best practices or at least find what's causing this issue, but I have been unable to find anything that actually fixed the issue.

I have a significant amount of [detached DOMs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n27T9.png) and have tried to analyze them more closely using Google Chrome's console, but have been unsuccessful.

**Attempted Fixes:**

- Moving everything to do with adding handlers into the map initialization function (as displayed below), but that did not seem to improve it by much.
- Loading any Bing Maps modules from the map initialization function (as displayed below). This cleaned the code up quite a bit, but didn't seem to have much of an affect on the memory usage.
- Loading the map synchronously. However, this seemed to break just about everything to do with Bing Maps on the site.
- Stopped disposing of the Map upon receiving a message. This assisted in key usage, but did not help with the memory usage.

**Relevant code:**

---

Here is the map initialization function (run asynchronously by the Bing Maps call in the HTML):

```
function initialize () {
const CENTER = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.96375272262944, -93.2353971897461);

// Assigns the zoom depending on whether the device is a mobile device or not
if (isMobile()) {
    zoom = 12;
} else {
    zoom = 13;
}

// Initialize the map
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    credentials: API_KEY,
    minZoom: zoom,
    center: CENTER,
    disableStreetside: true,
    disableStreetsideAutoCoverage: true,
    enableClickableLogo: false,
    showLocateMeButton: false,
    showMapTypeSelector: false
});

bus1 = {
    assignment: null,
    destination: null,
    distance: null,
    eta: null,
    location: null,
    mph: null,
    name: null,
    pin: new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
        icon: 'img/bus1.png',
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(14, 44),
        visible: false,
        text: "",
        title: ""
    }),
    polylineRender: null,
    time: null,
    timeout: null,
};
bus2 = {
    assignment: null,
    destination: null,
    distance: null,
    eta: null,
    location: null,
    mph: null,
    name: null,
    pin: new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
        icon: 'img/bus2.png',
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(14, 44),
        visible: false,
        text: "",
        title: ""
    }),
    polylineRender: null,
    time: null,
    timeout: null,
};
bus3 = {
    assignment: null,
    destination: null,
    distance: null,
    eta: null,
    location: null,
    mph: null,
    name: null,
    pin: new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), {
        icon: 'img/bus3.png',
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(14, 44),
        visible: false,
        text: "",
        title: ""
    }),
    polylineRender: null,
    time: null,
    timeout: null,
};

buses = [bus1, bus2, bus3];

// Add the traffic layer
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', function () {
    trafficLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map);
});

// Add the directions manager
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
    bus1.polylineRender = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
    bus2.polylineRender = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
    bus3.polylineRender = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus1.polylineRender, 'directionsError', function (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
    });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus1.polylineRender, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus2.polylineRender, 'directionsError', function (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
    });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus2.polylineRender, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus3.polylineRender, 'directionsError', function (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e.message + "\r\nResponse Code: " + e.responseCode);
    });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bus3.polylineRender, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);
});

// Defines the polygons surrounding each campus
polygonArrSTP = [
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94619673931851, -93.19240808486938),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.941321471037966, -93.19249391555786),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94130628263941, -93.19764375686646),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.93790398010943, -93.1975257396698),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.937926764055824, -93.1924831867218),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94164802063501, -93.19241881370544),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94164802063501, -93.18739771842957),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94618914576464, -93.18735480308533),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.94618914576464, -93.1924295425415),
];
polygonArrMPLS = [
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.97380025938377, -93.2795798778534),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.97295018417148, -93.27883958816528),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.97264658282772, -93.27782034873962),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.973595331690625, -93.27698349952698),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.9745744240603, -93.27614665031433),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.97501463068608, -93.27712297439575),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.9747205274961, -93.27738046646118),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.974339139822895, -93.27832460403442),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.97380025938377, -93.2795798778534)
];

// Adds the campus polygons to the map
polygonMPLS = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(polygonArrMPLS, {
    fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeThickness: 2
});
polygonSTP = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(polygonArrSTP, {
    fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeThickness: 2
});

// Assign the polygons to the Map
map.entities.push(polygonMPLS);
map.entities.push(polygonSTP);

// Set the toggle for advanced mode
advancedModeEnabled = false;

generateBusStats();
subscribeToPubnub();

console.log("Initialization complete.");
}
```

---

Here is the function that runs upon receiving a message:

```
function redraw(payload) {

// If the user is does not have the page active, the payload is refused
if (!acceptingPayloads) {
    return false;
}

let location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(payload.message.lat, payload.message.lng);
let name = payload.message.name;
let dest = payload.message.dest;
let mph = payload.message.mph;

const STP = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.9416428, -93.1917952);
const MPLS = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(44.9747502, -93.2774464);

if (dest.toUpperCase() === "S") {
    dest = {letter: "S", name: "St. Paul", coords: STP};
} else if (dest.toUpperCase() === "M") {
    dest = {letter: "M", name: "Minneapolis", coords: MPLS};
} else {
    dest = null;
}

console.log(name + ": " + location.latitude + ", " + location.longitude + " - " + dest.name + " - " + mph + " mph");

// Gets the bus object that the payload was sent from
currentBus = getCurrentBus(name);

// Removes the timeout for the current bus
if (currentBus.timeout !== null) {
    clearTimeout(currentBus.timeout);
}

currentBus.location = location;
currentBus.destination = dest;
currentBus.mph = mph;
currentBus.time = Date.now();
currentBus.name = name;

// Restart the timeout for the current bus
beginTimeout();

// Calculate the distance between the current bus and its destination
calcDistToDest();

$("." + currentBus.assignment + "-item").css('display', 'block')
}
```

---

Finally, here is the function that I use to get the distance between points:

```
function calcDistToDest() {

// Clear all information from the Directions Manager
currentBus.polylineRender.clearAll();

// Set Route Mode to driving and the render options
currentBus.polylineRender.setRequestOptions({
    routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving
});
currentBus.polylineRender.setRenderOptions({
    autoUpdateMapView: false,
    drivingPolylineOptions: {
        visible: POLYLINE_VISIBILITY
    },
    waypointPushpinOptions: {
        visible: false
    },
    firstWaypointPushpinOptions: {
        anchor: currentBus.pin.getAnchor(),
        icon: currentBus.pin.getIcon(),
        title: currentBus.pin.getTitle(),
        text: currentBus.pin.getText()
    }
});

// Sets the waypoint of the bus's current position and destination
currentBus.polylineRender.addWaypoint( new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    location: currentBus.location
}));
currentBus.polylineRender.addWaypoint( new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    location: currentBus.destination.coords
}));

// Calculate the directions
currentBus.polylineRender.calculateDirections();
}
```

---

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to find out what is causing this issue, an actual resolution to the issue if it's simple and I'm just missing something obvious, or the best practices to avoid this issue in the first place.

**Note:** My apologies for posting so much code. It's hard to determine what code to post because I don't really know what section of the code is causing the issue. Let me know if this needs to be modified or if any other information is needed and I would be happy to oblige. I also left out a lot of seemingly irrelevant JS code from the same file, I'd be happy to add it if need be.

Comment: Which branch of Bing Maps V8 are you using? The frozen branch hasn't been updated in over a year and has a lot of known memory leaks, many of these are fixed in the main release branch. There is a couple more fixes in the experimental branch. Which browser are you using, I believe the issue you are reporting is a known issue with IE.

Comment: So I've been using the release branch. This issue has been happening on Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge seemingly at the same rate.

Comment: Can you try the experimental branch to see if the issue is still there. If it has been resolved, it likely will be in the main release branch either in the next week if it made it in time for the release, or near the end of September.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory leaks were primarily resolved via the implementation of the experimental branch of Bing Maps as suggested by [rbrundritt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245450/rbrundritt).

Here is an example of how to import Bing Maps using the experimental branch:

```
<script src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=experimental&callback=[Insert callback function]' async defer></script>
```

I was later able to switch back to the release branch as the fixes for the memory leaks were pushed to that branch. More information regarding the Bing Maps Map Control Branches can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712554.aspx).